# Deleting image chips shown from the DB reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am showing images as chips by getting data from the DB. How to delete the image chip displayed by db?

display of images from db -

```
{user.isImageUploaded != null ?
     <div >
          <p>
      {user.isImageUploaded.map(item => {
       const datatypeVar = item.fileType;
       const dataimageCode = item.filedata;
       const dataName = item.fileName
       return (
               <Chip
               label="Basic"
              size="small"
              label={dataName}
             onDelete={() => this.handleImgDelete(dataName)}
               avatar={
               <Avatar variant="rounded" alt="Remy Sharp" src= 
                         {`data:${datatypeVar};base64,${dataimageCode}`} />
                       }/>
                        )
                      })} : null}
```

user.isImageUploaded is the data mapped from the database. How to write the handleImgDelete?

Comment: Do you only want to delete the chip or the actual data in your DB?

Comment: From db as well. But I can do that while posting it back to db.

Comment: Ah I see, well in that case I would remove it from the db, and get the new info which will also result in the chip being removed. I personally prefer making sure the same data is shown on the front-end as the data in the db

Comment: The thing is the user has a chance to edit so I want a delete function so its removed from the isImageUploaded array so that I can post the remaining array again to the db

Comment: I see, well my way of doing it would be to copy the user object, then edit the isImageUploaded array and then sending the copied user object back to the DB. You can remove the value from the array by using array.splice(), I will put some code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

First of we need the index of the value that needs to be removed from the array, this can be done by using the second paramater of the .map function.

```
.map((item, index) => { do some stuff here })
```

Item will be the actual image and index will be the index of the current image in the array (who would have guessed XD)

So instead of giving dataName to the handeImgDelete you would give the index

```
{user.isImageUploaded != null ?
     <div >
          <p>
      {user.isImageUploaded.map((item, index) => {
       const datatypeVar = item.fileType;
       const dataimageCode = item.filedata;
       const dataName = item.fileName
       return (
               <Chip
               label="Basic"
              size="small"
              label={dataName}
             onDelete={() => this.handleImgDelete(index)}
               avatar={
               <Avatar variant="rounded" alt="Remy Sharp" src= 
                         {`data:${datatypeVar};base64,${dataimageCode}`} />
                       }/>
                        )
                      })} : null}
```

Your handleImgDelete could be something like this:

```
const handleImageDelete(index) => {
  // I am aware that this is a bad way of deep cloning a object (if you encounter problems with this you could use https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep)

  let userCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
  
  userCopy.isImageUploaded.splice(index, 1)
  
  // Do stuff here to send to the db
}
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(user) - in this line what does the user contain?? When I use user.isImageUploaded to map, user is just a var to map the values

Comment: data from db is inside a postData array which I map using postData.map(user => {return user.imageUploaded.....//etc})
p.s postData has other data such as title and  description and isImageUploaded is an array in it

Comment: also I get the error cannot read property splice of undefined

Comment: Postdata is a array with different values? You say it has title and description but also user data? Why is postdata an array and not an object in that case?

Comment: Okay so basically PostData is where the axios get data has been stored (which includes title description, isImageUploaded etc). From that I mapped isImageUploaded to be displayed as above shown in code.

Comment: Can you show an example of PostData? So i know what you mean